# Using paraboloidal coordinates

Tags: analysis, coordinate-systems

I have the [3-dimensional paraboloidal coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloidal_coordinates)

$$s_{\pm}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\pm z$$
$$\phi=ArcTan(y/x)$$
with the inverse transformation
$$x=\sqrt{s_+ \cdot s_-}\cdot cos(\phi)$$
$$y=\sqrt{s_+ \cdot s_-}\cdot sin(\phi)$$
$$z=\frac{s_+ - s_-}{2}$$

Questions:

1. Properties in integration: Suppose I have $ I= \int_{0}^{\infty} ds_+ \int_{0}^{\infty} ds_- f(s_+,s_-) \cdot \delta(s_+ - t)$, can I naively apply the Dirac-Delta and get $I=\int_{0}^{\infty} ds_- f(t,s_-)$ ?
2. Properties in differentiation: Suppose I have $D=\frac{\partial}{\partial s_-} e^{2\cdot s_-} \cdot s_+$, can I naively ignore the $s_+$ Term and get $D=2\cdot e^{2\cdot s_-} \cdot s_+$ ?

Every hint will be much appreciated!

Comment: If you keep changing the question every other day, then it becomes hard for people (like me) to think of an answer.

Comment: Sorry Han, i'm trying to update on progress on my side. and this was actually a partial answere to my previous question (what is this coordinate system). dont plan to change anymore, as the questions posted now. so every explanation of the questions now will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote is

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
s_+ &=& \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} + z,\\
s_- &=& \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} - z.\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

As both are positive, we can take the square root, thus

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
t_+ &=& \sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} + z},\\
t_- &=& \sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} - z}.\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Note that

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
t_+ t_- &=& \sqrt{x^2+y^2},\\
\frac{t_+^2 - t_-^2}{2} &=& z,
\end{eqnarray}
$$

so

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& \cos(\phi) t_+ t_-,\\
y &=& \sin(\phi) t_+ t_-,\\
z &=& \frac{t_+^2 - t_-^2}{2}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

These coordinates are known as *Paraboloidal* coordinates $(\phi,u,v)$.

What you have defined is $(\phi,s_+,s_-) = (\phi,u^2,v^2)$.

We can call then the *partly squared paraboloidal* or the *NicoDean* coordinates...

Comment: Wonderful, thanks. (Actually as you see, I was also already on the right track; funny that its not answered for 12days, then within 10mins we both found the answere ;) ). Thanks for making it so precice how the trafo works. Do you also know something about the two remaining questions about how to apply those coorindates? Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes such questions pop up - when I see them I try to give an answer...

As for the other questions - I need to think about them...

Comment: These properties 1. and 2. are valid when $s_+$ and $s_-$ are independant and they are.

Same holds for $r$ and $\theta$ for spherical co-ordinates...

Comment: sure, of course, you are right! thanks. +50 :)